# How to get JSON object to React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a React App with AXIOS. I need to get some JSON data from back end and change the State with that data. **When I get the object and mapping to my state, the state is only setting for the last element of the object. So I can only see the last element in the state.** How I can get all the elements to the state?

My API call is as follows

```
API.post('viewallusers', [], config)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        const allUsers = data.response.AllUsers;
        allUsers
          .map(user => {
            return (
              this.setState({
                data: [
                  createData(
                    user.name,
                    user.id,
                    user.email
                  )
                ]
              })
            )
          })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
```

JSON data:

```
{response :
  {AllUsers :
    0 : {name: "Amy", id: 1, email: "myEmail1"},
    1 : {name: "Doris", id: 2, email: "myEmail2"},
    2 : {name: "Jase", id: 3, email: "myEmail3"}
  }
}
```

I expect the the state "data" is to be set as follows:

```
data : [
  createData("Amy",1,"myEmail1"),
  createData("Doris",2,"myEmail2"),
  createData("Jase",3,"myEmail3")
]
```

But the actual state after getting the JSON data is

```
data : [
  createData("Jase",3,"myEmail3")
]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first map the data then set entire state.

```
API.post('viewallusers', [], config)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({
      data: data.response.AllUsers.map(user => (createData(user.name, user.id, user.email)))
    })
  })
```

Or use callback version of `setState` and manually merge `state.data` (NOT recommended in this particular case)

```
API.post('viewallusers', [], config)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    data.response.AllUsers.forEach(user => {
      this.setState(prev =>
        ({...prev, data: [prev.data, createData(user.name, user.id, user.email)]})
      )
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably happens because `setState` doesn't do a **deep merge**. So if you have in state

```
state = {
    key1: 123,
    key2: {
        test1: 1,
        test2: 2

    }

}
```

And you do

```
this.setState({
    key2: {
        test1: 4
    }

})
```

You will end up with

```
state = {
    key1: 123,
    key2: {
        test1: 4
    }

}
```

You have to do instead:

```
this.setState((ps) => ({
    key2: {
        ...ps.key2,
        test1: 4
    }

}));
```

Similar approach works if value for `key2` is array. Or alternatively you can first map all the data and then do a `setState` as suggested in other answer.